# Exclude some words with regexp

Tags: regex

I have the text:

> text text text text [text] text text -.[text1] -.[text2]

I want to extract only the words with only brakets [], exluding words with -.[

for this example i want only [text] and no -.[text1] and -.[text2]

Ty!

Comment: What language/library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work, assuming the language or library you are using supports lookbehind:

```
(?<!-\.)\[[^\]]*\]
```

Explanation:

```
(?<!-\.)    # fail if the previous characters are '-.'
\[          # match a literal '['
[^\]]*      # match any number of characters that are not ']'
\]          # match a literal ']'
```

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/HqdR3tZy9R